# Discord Bot cannot Kick/Ban members

Tags: discord.py

The kick command in the discord bot I made is not working.  I used the "-kick @user" command to do so. But it does nothing. No error, nothing.

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
   await member.kick(reason=reason)
   await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been kicked')
client.run('Token')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `member` is `None`, you have to enable `intents.members` in order it to work:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents)
```

Also make sure to enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

[docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents)

Comment: I have given all admin privileges to the BOT and myself. Any other solution?

Comment: No error. Just doesn't work. All the other functions I have added works flawlessly.

Comment: well, I copied your code and it works fine for me, do you have an `on_message` event?

Comment: Yes I do have it.

Comment: do you have `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of it?

Comment: then add it, and tell me if the command works

Comment: No, i do not have that command. This is the only command await member.kick(reason=reason)

Comment: you just told me you have an `on_message` event, if you *still* do, at the end of it add `await client.process_commands(message)`

Comment: "do you have await client.process_commands(message) at the end of it?"

I don't use that command to run the function (message)

Comment: I think we're not understanding each other.

Comment: Do you mind joining my server and discussing it there. The chat is a bit long in here

Comment: I can, link please

Comment: It works now.  Thank you so much for your help

Comment: okay, remmeber to acceptp the answer if it helped