# Why doesn't my discord bot kick command work?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to make my bot kick a member when I type the command ".kick @user" in Discord, I have referred to many YouTube videos, they have all pointed to the same code, however it doesn't work for me. So, how do I kick a member?

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

# To kick user
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member = None, *, reason = None):
  await member.kick(reason = reason)
```

Comment: Do you have any intents enabled?

Comment: What do you mean by intents?

Comment: Have a look at this question here: [Discord Bot cannot Kick/Ban members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65150414/discord-bot-cannot-kick-ban-members)

Comment: So as my answer got deleted here is the answer: You need to enable Intents, which you did, secondly your `on_message` event is blocking the commands. Have a look at the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Intents are missing and your `on_message` events stop the commands from working.

**For the Intents:**

Make sure to turn them on in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) for your application.

**You can find them here:** *Navigate to your Application -> Bot -> Scroll down -> Make your ticks*

**To implement them to your code you can use the following:**

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all() # Imports all the Intents
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="YourPrefix", intents=intents)
```

***Or just the members Intent to find/kick a member:***

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default() # Imports the default intents
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="YourPrefix", intents=intents)
```

*You can also have a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html) for more information*

**For the `on_message` event:**

You are overrdining the default `on_message` event. To fix this simply **add the following** to your code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    greeting1 = re.compile(f"hello <@!?{client.user.id}>")
    if greeting1.match(message.content.lower()) is not None:
        await message.channel.send("Hello {}".format(message.author.mention) + "!")
    if greeting1.match(message.content.upper()) is not None:
        await message.channel.send("Hello {}".format(message.author.mention) + "!")

    greeting2 = re.compile(f"hey <@!?{client.user.id}>")
    if greeting2.match(message.content.lower()) is not None:
        await message.channel.send("Hey {}".format(message.author.mention) + "!")
    if greeting2.match(message.content.upper()) is not None:
        await message.channel.send("Hey {}".format(message.author.mention) + "!")

    await client.process_commands(message) # Allows commands to work
```

*Make sure to indent the code in the right way!*

Comment: it still doesn't work. Here's the link to my code: https://replit.com/@kooldamian28/openbot

Comment: @kooldamian28 The error now comes from your `on_message` events. Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things why this may not be working, the first is that you do not have the intents enabled, you can enable them this way:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(intents=intents, command_prefix=".")
```

The other is that it is possible that the bot does not have enough permissions to kicke the user and the third is that simply the user role is above the bot role. The command is well done so don't worry about changing things in this code.

I hope this helped you.